# Biblatex: Local change in sorting order in references

Tags: biblatex, sorting

Is it possible to generate a local change in the sorting order in the references? I'm using the `authortitle-icomp` style which is working very well for me. There is just one minor problem. I would like to sort a number of entries by the number of the series without affecting all '@book' entries with `number` and `series`. (Without the change they are ordered jT77a, jT77, jT77b and I need jT77a, jT77b, jT77)

```
@book{jT77a,
author = {John~R.~R. Tolkien},
series = {Der Herr der Ringe},
number = {1},
title = {Die Gefährten},
year = {1977},
edition = {},
publisher = {Hobbit-Presse im Klett-Verlag},
location = {Stuttgart},
} 

@book{jT77b,
author = {John~R.~R. Tolkien},
series = {Der Herr der Ringe},
number = {2},
title = {Die zwei Türme},
year = {1977},
edition = {},
publisher = {Hobbit-Presse im Klett-Verlag},
location = {Stuttgart},
} 

@book{jT77,
author = {John~R.~R. Tolkien},
series = {Der Herr der Ringe},
number = {3},
title = {Die Rückkehr des Königs},
year = {1977},
edition = {},
publisher = {Hobbit-Presse im Klett-Verlag},
location = {Stuttgart},
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you follow the example of the `knuth:ct:_` works in [`biblatex-examples.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib)

You would then use `maintitle` instead of `series` and `volume` in lieu of `number`.
Then add a `sortyear` field with content `<year>-<volume>` and a `sorttitle` with content `<maintitle> <volume>`. The former is so name-year sort schemes do the right thing, the latter is for name-title schemes.

```
@book{jT77a,
  author    = {John R. R. Tolkien},
  maintitle = {Der Herr der Ringe},
  volume    = {1},
  title     = {Die Gefährten},
  year      = {1977},
  publisher = {Klett-Cotta},
  location  = {Stuttgart},
  sorttitle = {Der Herr der Ringe 1},
  sortyear  = {1977-1},
} 

@book{jT77b,
  author    = {John R. R. Tolkien},
  maintitle = {Der Herr der Ringe},
  volume    = {2},
  title     = {Die zwei Türme},
  year      = {1977},
  publisher = {Klett-Cotta},
  location  = {Stuttgart},
  sorttitle = {Der Herr der Ringe 2},
  sortyear  = {1977-2},
} 

@book{jT77,
  author    = {John R. R. Tolkien},
  maintitle = {Der Herr der Ringe},
  volume    = {3},
  title     = {Die Rückkehr des Königs},
  year      = {1977},
  publisher = {Klett-Cotta},
  location  = {Stuttgart},
  sorttitle = {Der Herr der Ringe 3},
  sortyear  = {1977-3},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ibid]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{jT77a,
  author    = {John R. R. Tolkien},
  maintitle = {Der Herr der Ringe},
  volume    = {1},
  title     = {Die Gefährten},
  year      = {1977},
  publisher = {Klett-Cotta},
  location  = {Stuttgart},
  sorttitle = {Der Herr der Ringe 1},
  sortyear  = {1977-1},
} 

@book{jT77b,
  author    = {John R. R. Tolkien},
  maintitle = {Der Herr der Ringe},
  volume    = {2},
  title     = {Die zwei Türme},
  year      = {1977},
  publisher = {Klett-Cotta},
  location  = {Stuttgart},
  sorttitle = {Der Herr der Ringe 2},
  sortyear  = {1977-2},
} 

@book{jT77,
  author    = {John R. R. Tolkien},
  maintitle = {Der Herr der Ringe},
  volume    = {3},
  title     = {Die Rückkehr des Königs},
  year      = {1977},
  publisher = {Klett-Cotta},
  location  = {Stuttgart},
  sorttitle = {Der Herr der Ringe 3},
  sortyear  = {1977-3},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewrobustcmd*{\bibnamedelimb}{\addnbspace}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> Tolkien, John R. R. *Der Herr der Ringe.* Bd. 1: *Die Gefährten.* Stuttgart: Klett-Cotta, 1977.
>
> — *Der Herr der Ringe.* Bd. 2: *Die zwei Türme.* Stuttgart: Klett-Cotta, 1977.
>
> — *Der Herr der Ringe.* Bd. 3: *Die Rückkehr des Königs.* Stuttgart: Klett-Cotta, 1977.

Comment: I have also removed the non-breaking spaces between the initials, if you want those, you better add them in via `\bibinitdelim`, `\bibnamedelima` and friends. Actually, you should only need `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibnamedelimb}{\addnbspace}` to get the same effect.