# Series not appearing in Biber natbib APA inproceedings reference

Tags: biblatex, natbib, biber, apa-style

I'm using Biber/bibLaTeX with the following options:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

In references of the type `inproceedings` I don't get the series. Here is an example:

[image]

As you see, having just “Vol. 7816” without mentioning the series *Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science* of which it is a volume, makes no sense, and this information is crucial.

Here is the BIB code of the reference:

```
@inproceedings{yh13cicling2,
   Author = {Haralambous, Yannis},
   Booktitle = {{CICLing 2013: 14th International Conference on Intelligent Text Processing and Computational Linguistics, Samos}},
   Pages = {201--217},
   Series = {Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
   Title = {New Perspectives in Sinographic Language Processing Through the Use of Character Structure},
   Volume = {7816},
   Year = {2013}}
```

How can I make the series appear?

Comment: I don't think that there is code. You could add an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues, a related discussion seems to be https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/15.

Comment: I'll say what I always want to say when there is a question about APA, but don't always do: If the behaviour `biblatex-apa` exhibits does not conform to APA style as outlined in the APA manual, please report this at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues (ideally with a reference to the relevant APA rules). If this is just an extension of APA that might come in handy for your non-APA purposes, I recommend not using `biblatex-apa`, but rather building a style upon one of the standard styles (`style=authoryear` for example) instead. ...

Comment: ... `biblatex-apa` has to jump through a lot of hoops and has to do quite some tricks to implement APA style and that means that it can be quite a bit less customisable in some areas than the standard styles. In any case `biblatex-apa` wasn't written specifically with the intention of being easily customisable, whereas the standard styles can be seen as a basis to start from if you need a different style.

Comment: Thanks but, what I'm asking is not “customization,” I just want to avoid information disappearing, and the series of a book is crucial information, in particular if you have the volume number…

Comment: The question is whether or not the APA manual says the information should be appearing. As I said `biblatex-apa`'s only aim is to provide a style that implements APA guidelines by the book. If APA guidelines usually drop the series info, then this is the expected outcome.

Comment: I haven't checked but how can you possibly have “Vol. 7816” without saying of what it is a volume???

Comment: As I commented on the `biblatex-apa` bugtracker that is an input problem. `series`+`volume` don't go together: Either use `series`+`number` or `maintitle`+`volume`. The combination `series`+`volume` may give weird results. (Note that this is one of the things where classical BibTeX and `biblatex` differ.)

Comment: As I answered on `biblatex-apa` when I use series+number, then neither of them appears, and when I use maintitle+volume I get first the Series, then the Book title and then the number, which is absurd: *Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science. CICLing 2013: 14th International Conference on Intelligent Text Processing and Computational Linguistics, Samos* (Vol. 7816, pp. 201-271). The volume number should be close to the series name, since it is a volume of that series. I would expect: *CICLing 2013…Linguistics. Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science*, vol. 7816, pp. 201-271. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues at play with the `.bib` entry shown in the question and the style you use (`apa`).

## Use `series`+`number`

The first issue is that for `biblatex` the correct input for a series is slightly different from the usual input for most BibTeX styles. Where BibTeX uses the two fields `series`+`volume` `biblatex` has two possible combinations

- `series`+`number` for loose series (usually consisting of many publications published by a variety of different authors over a long period of time) and
- `maintitle`+`volume` for a tighter multi-volume publication (usually such a work involves fewer publications and the same or at least a more homogeneous set of authors over a shorter period of time).

With `biblatex` it is generally not a good idea to mix the two approaches.

[The `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) explains the difference in 2.3.7 *Publication and Journal Series*, p. 37 as follows

> The series field is used by traditional BibTeX styles both for the main title of a multi-volume work and for a publication series, i.e., a loosely related sequence of books by the same publisher which deal with the same general topic or belong to the same field of research. This may be ambiguous. This package introduces a `maintitle` field for multi-volume works and employs `series` for publication series only. The volume or number of a book in the series goes in the `number` field in this case.

This is also discussed in more detail in [Omit Vol and Issue/No?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457598/35864), examples can be found at [Biblatex: Local change in sorting order in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270399/35864), [BibLaTeX: how to reverse order of volume and series?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411516/35864), [biblatex-dw bibliography formatting @incollection volume number after series name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369345/35864).

In your case then, the `.bib` file for `biblatex` should probably look like

```
@inproceedings{yh13cicling2,
   author    = {Haralambous, Yannis},
   title     = {New Perspectives in Sinographic Language Processing
                Through the Use of Character Structure},
   booktitle = {{CICLing} 2013: 14th International Conference on
                Intelligent Text Processing and Computational Linguistics, {Samos}},
   year      = {2013},
   pages     = {201--217},
   series    = {Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
   number    = {7816},
}
```

## But APA style doesn't show `series`+`number`!

In your setup with `biblatex-apa` there is a second issue: `biblatex-apa` does not print the combination `series`+`number` at all in the bibliography. I don't have the APA manual at hand, but from reading https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/15 and previous research it is my understanding that the APA guidelines (6th ed.) don't treat publication series extensively and only mention them once in a fairly ambiguous way (in the one example that involves a "series" in the APA manual we could also be talking about `maintitle`+`volume`; the output in the example certainly looks more like it).

If you have evidence that the APA guidelines require that `series`+`number` be shown in a different way, then you can – and should! – take this to the `biblatex-apa` bug tracker (cf. https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/80). At the moment it is my understanding that you are not dead-set on following APA guidelines, but that you rather use `biblatex-apa` as a base style because you like it or it comes closest to what you expect and you want to display `series`+`number` regardless of what the APA says. In that case I should mention that I generally recommend using `biblatex-apa` only if you want to follow APA guidelines, if you are just looking for a nice author-year citation/bibliography style that can be customised to your needs, you are usually better off with one of the standard styles. `biblatex-apa` needs to do some heavy lifting to implement the APA guidelines as closely as possible and can not always – an is not intended to – be as easily customised as the standard styles.

You can find an attempt at hacking `biblatex-apa` to display `series`+`number` at [Change 'Series' + 'Number' entries in bibliography with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324509/35864), but as I said before and also said over there, I don't recommend changing `biblatex-apa` that drastically. It is a better idea to go with a standard style instead.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. What would you suggest
as a standard style that comes close to APA? I mean a natbib
style where author names are included in citations (at full the first time and with et al. afterwards).

Comment: @yannis Pick one from the `authoryear` family (`style=authoryear`, `style=authoryear-ibid`, `style=authoryear-comp`,  `style=authoryear-icomp`). Of course this will not look exactly like APA and will not behave exactly like it, but for most people who are looking for author-year citations it is good enough (after a few modifications). By default `biblatex` does not print the full author lists for first citations and a shortened list afterwards, but that can be implemented, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48846/35864

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I took `authoryear-ibid` and it looks fine. In the references, multiple entries with the same authors have an em-dash instead of the authors' names, how can I replace this by something longer (e.g., a `\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{.4pt}`) ?

Comment: OK, I found it: to change the dash you just redefine `\bibnamedash` like this: `\def\bibnamedash{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt} }`.

Comment: @yannis To mirror the definition in `biblatex.def` I would probably say `\renewcommand\bibnamedash{\mbox{\rule[.5ex]{15mm}{0.4pt}\space}}`, but the difference hardly matters. (Though I do strongly prefer `\renewcommand` over `\def` here.)